# fullcalendar full vertical borders

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

My fullcalendar collided with my bootstrap CSS file, so I must set my style manually. (I use fullcalendar 2.7.3)

I want to have red borders (horizontal and vertical). 
I changed:

```
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td,
.fc-row .fc-helper-skeleton td{...}
```

and that created me horizontal and vertical borders. But the vertical borders only showed in the head of the cell. (Screenshot) How can I insert a full vertical border.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[fullcalendar.min.css](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.3/fullcalendar.min.css) uses this code for the `border-color` property:

```
.fc-unthemed .fc-content, 
.fc-unthemed .fc-divider,
.fc-unthemed .fc-popover,
.fc-unthemed .fc-row,
.fc-unthemed tbody,
.fc-unthemed td,
.fc-unthemed th,
.fc-unthemed thead { 
  border-color: #ddd 
}
```

So you can copy this fragment and set the color that you need:

```
.fc-unthemed .fc-content, 
.fc-unthemed .fc-divider,
.fc-unthemed .fc-popover,
.fc-unthemed .fc-row,
.fc-unthemed tbody,
.fc-unthemed td,
.fc-unthemed th,
.fc-unthemed thead { 
  border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: that was my first try, but my boostrap css file collided with that (so my borders was white). In addition i use (theme:true;) so jquery don't use the unthemed class.

Comment: @Ckappo Can you give me the link to your page?

Comment: now i switch to theme:false, and set up my border style with !important. It work now. Thx Gleb